# ¿Es correcto usar el mismo array como entrada y salida en sprintf?

Tags: c++, array

Me he encontrado el siguiente código :

```
char query[255];
sprintf(query, "SELECT NOMBRE, ");
switch (tipo)
{
    case TIPO_1:
        sprintf(query, "%s ID", query);
        break;
    case TIPO_2:
        sprintf(query, "%s APELLIDO", query);
        break;
}
```

Y lo que me inquieta es el uso de `query` haciendo el papel tanto de parámetro de lectura como de escritura de `sprintf`.
El código funciona bien y hace lo que de el se espera en nuestro compilador y en nuestras pruebas.

Suponiendo que no se excede el tamaño del array. Y que siempre que se usa query como parámetro de lectura es el primer parámetro tras el de formato y el formato empieza por "%s".
¿Es un uso correcto? ¿O hay alguna situación en que podría funcionar mal?

Comment: la respuesta depende 100% de la implementación de sprintf. si sprintf compone el resultado en un buffer intermedio y luego lo copia en el buffer de salida no pasa nada. pero si trabaja directo en el buffer de salida el resultado de la función puede no ser lo esperado. Considerando la portabilidad, es una mala idea.

Comment: sprintf es una función que forma parte del standard de C++. Por ejemplo, en memmove el standard garantiza que se pueden copiar buffers solapados y en memcpy el standard no lo garantiza. Mi pregunta es por tanto si para sprintf hay una garantía como la que hay para memmove o si no existe esa garantía como en memcpy.

Comment: El compilador de Ideone, desde luego, da un resultado incorrecto en algunos casos: https://ideone.com/UKVoAn (basta con que el `%s` esté en cualquier punto excepto al principio).

Comment: @Darkhogg , fíjate que en la pregunta especifico que el formato empieza siempre por "%s", que no es el caso de tu programa ejemplo de ideone. He probado con un formato empezando por "%s" y sí que funciona bien en ideone : https://ideone.com/O82Fh5 .

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Cierto, no me había fijado. Ese es precisamente el caso en el que *aparentemente* siempre funciona. Yo desde luego no me fiaría, tiene pinta de ser casual y dependiente de la implementación. Si la implementación diese con UB en este caso, optimizar ese código podría hacer que dejara de funcionar, mismamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si revisamos lo que dice la documentación de la función en [GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Formatted-Output-Functions):

> The behavior of this function is undefined if copying takes place between objects that overlap—for example, if s is also given as an argument to be printed under control of the ‘%s’ conversion. See Copying and Concatenation.

En tu caso estás solapando el buffer de entrada con el de salida luego el resultado, como han indicado en el primer comentario, depende únicamente de la implementación que uses en cada momento.

En cualquier caso, aunque funcione para situaciones concretas, es algo a evitar dada la aleatoriedad del resultado. Hay soluciones mucho más robustas que requieren únicamente el uso de una variable adicional.

Answer (score 1):

Con respecto a las funciones de la libraría estándar de C como `sprintf`, C++ referencia al estándar de C, con algunas cualificaciones (pero ninguna para `sprintf`). Por su parte, el estándar de C (en §7.19.6.6 en C99, §7.21.6.6 en C11) dice que si se produce una copia entre objetos que se solapan, se produce comportamiento indefinido.

Según ambos estándares, en cuanto se produce comportamiento indefinido el resultado puede ser impredecible.

Comment: ¿La copia del standard de c++11 que usas es accesible online? En el draft que uso yo no aparece el §7.21.6.6  : http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf

Comment: Es §7.21.6.6 en el estándar de C, en el de C++ se referencia en §1.2.2, §17.2 y §27.9.2